# Может ли андроид приложение установиться не в папку Android/data/data?

Tags: android, root

У меня такой вопрос: если приложение было установлено в стандартную папку, то может ли оно скопировать себя в другую папку (не предназначенную для хранения приложений) и запуститься оттуда? Мне кажется, что в таком случае приложение не будет видно через стандартные `Настройки`.

**P.S.** Исправьте если в чём ошибся.

Comment: Подозреваю, что зависит от того, сколько и каких прав ты ему дал, а ещё от наличия рута. https://habr.com/ru/post/541190/

Comment: А если приложению доступен рут?

Comment: Я бы предположил, что имея рутовые права приложение может сделать что угодно. Но вообще-то я не знаю.

Comment: А приложение `Настройки` ищет приложения по всем папкам или только в data/data/ ? Потому что, если это так, то очень удобно прятать вредоносные приложения в системе,  особенно если будут продолжать работать разрешение на загрузку при старте системы, и соответствующий ресивер.